# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when setting a property on react-native

Tags: ios, swift, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to link my Swift view with my React-Native project. I figured out how to display it, but now when I'm trying to set a property, I'm having this error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Switch setMessage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f96b270de70'
```

In my react-native code, I'm doing:

```
const SwitchNative = requireNativeComponent('Switch', Switch);

class Switch extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <SwitchNative message="message will be" style={this.props.style} />
    );
  }
}
```

Then doing this in my **SwiftBridge**:

```
// SwiftBridge.h

#import "RCTView.h"

@interface SwitchBridge : RCTView

  @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *message;

@end

// SwiftBridge.m

#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "RCTViewManager.h"
#import "SwitchBridge.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(SwitchManager, RCTViewManager)

  RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(message, NSString)

@end
```

Then finally I have this in my Swift class `Switch.swift`:

```
...
public func setMessage(message: String) {
  NSLog("It's working well");
}
...
```

Not sure why it can't find my `setMessage` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React Native is trying to call `-[Switch setMessage:]` but you've defined `-[Switch setMessage]` without any parameters. Add a parameter to your Swift method signature:

```
public func setMessage(_ message: String)
```

You might also need to annotate your method with `@objc` depending on your version of Swift.

Comment: Ah I actually tried this too and it didn't work either. I edited my question. How do I annotate?

Comment: In case anyone else wonders, @objc(setMessage:) func setMessage(_ message: String)

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is now in swift,

```
@objc(setMessage:)
public func setMessage(message: String) {
  NSLog("It's working well");
}
```

This is change for Swift > 3.2, Mac High Sierra and React Native >= 0.43

Answer (score 0):

For anyone might be searching for passing an array of objects from React-Native (I ran into this issue while doing that):

`YourView.h`:

```objectivec
@interface YourView : RCTView

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *markers;

@end
```

`YourView.m`:

```objectivec
...
RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY(markers, NSMutableArray, YourView)
{
  [view setMarkers:json];
}
```

`YourView.swift`:

```swift
@objc(setMarkers:)
public func setMarkers(json: NSMutableArray) {
    
}
```